# Add a demo button in react.jsx which will fill the form data

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a demo button. When I select that button it need to fill the form as the data I have given. I tried to implement a button but it is not worked.

This is my code  .jsx file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import { notification} from "antd";

export default class AddDepartment extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            admins:[],
            empId:[],
            admin_id:'',
            dept_id:'',
            dept_name:'',
            dept_manager_name:''
         }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchAdmins();
        this.fetchAdmins();
    }

    //Admin data as foreign key
    fetchAdmins = () =>{
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin-list/").then(res=>
        {
            const admins=res.data;
            this.setState({admins});
        }
        )
    }
    fetchEmployee = () => {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/employeeid/").then(res=>
        {
            const empId=res.data;
            this.setState({empId});
        }
        )

    }
    
    formData = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        this.setState({ radstatus: !this.state.radstatus });

        console.log(
            this.state.dept_name,
            this.state.dept_manager_name
        );
        console.log(this.state.radstatus);
        console.log(this.state.event);
    };

    drop = (e) =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
        console.log(this.state.event)
    }

    onCreateEmp = () => {
        console.log();
    }

    formSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const deptdata ={
            admin_id:this.state.admin_id,
            dept_id:this.state.dept_id,
            dept_name:this.state.dept_name,
            dept_manager_name:this.state.dept_manager_name,

        }

        console.log(deptdata)

        const args = {
            description:
              "Data added successfully",
            duration: 0,
          };
          notification.open(args);

        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/department-Create/";

        fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-type':'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(deptdata)
          }).then((response) => {
            alert(response)
          }).catch(function(err){
            alert(err)
          })
        }
   
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">

            <div className="col main">
                <h1 
                    style={{
                        color: "DodgerBlue",
                        fontSize: '30px',
                        fontWeight:"bold"}}>
                    <center>ADD DEPARTMENT</center>
                </h1>
                <br></br><br></br>
                <form  onSubmit= {this.formSubmit}
                        style={{
                            fontWeight:"bold"}}
                            >
                <Card style={{ width: 1000,}}>

                         <br></br>Admin ID :<select required onChange={this.formData} id="admin" name="admin_id" style={{border: "3px solid #ccc",float: "right",width: "68%",height:45}}>
                                    {this.state.admins.map((ad) =>{
                                        const adId = ad.id;
                                        const adName = ad.username;

                                        return(
                                        <option value={ad.id}>{ad.username}</option>
                                        );
                                    })}
                        </select> 
                       
                        <br></br><br></br>
                        <br></br>Department ID : <input required style={{border: "3px solid #ccc",float: "right",width: "68%",height:30}} type="text" onChange= {this.formData} name="dept_id"></input><br></br><br></br>
                        Name : <input required style={{border: "3px solid #ccc",float: "right",width: "68%",height:30}} type="text" onChange= {this.formData} name="dept_name" ></input><br></br><br></br>
                        Manager of Department : <input required style={{border: "3px solid #ccc",float: "right",width: "68%",height:30}} type="text" onChange= {this.formData} name="dept_manager_name" ></input><br></br><br></br>
                        
                        <br></br><br></br>
                    
                </Card>
            <div>
            <br></br><br></br><br></br>
                
            <input style={{width:"100%", cursor: "pointer",backgroundColor:"DodgerBlue",border:"none",padding:"12px 28px",margin:"2px 1px",borderRadius:"2px",fontWeight:"bold"}} type="submit" value="Add Department"></input>
            <button>DEMO</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>   
        

    </div>
    </div>
    )
}
}
```

Please help me to do this. How can I create a function that will fill the form (onClick={this.functionName) Then I need to add that function in onclick. After that when I select the button it need to fill the form.

These are the details i need to add----

admin_id = CR12A

Dept_id = CR101B

Dept_name = Decoration

Dept_manager_name = John

when I select the DEMO button the form will need to be filled with this data in the relevant input session.

Comment: You can create a method that'll update the state when you click on the button. Is your question on how to do that? Did you try some approach? Did it work? If not, what's the issue?

Comment: I tried to do. But it was not working.  'I tried to add the data in this. but it showed error 'demodata=()=>{}'

Comment: Under `componentDidMount` did you mean to call `his.fetchAdmins();` twice?

Comment: It need to be `this.fetchEmployee()`

Comment: You are not actually binding the value of the input element to the state of the application. Refer [Forms - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) on how to bind the value of input to a state.

Comment: Actually this form is working well. I can add the data manually and save it, Now i just need a method to fill the inputfield manually with a button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223402/discussion-between-debargha-roy-and-deepika).